# Flexslider thumbnails appear as multiple rows

Tags: html, css

Currently I have a flex slider that appears like this:
[image]

The more pictures I add the more rows the thumbnail area displays.  I'd like it to just be one row.  This is the default behavior but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  Here is the css code associated with Flex-control-thumbs

```css
.flex-control-thumbs {
    width: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: -40px; 
    text-align: center;
}
.flex-control-thumbs li {
    margin: 0 6px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    zoom: 1; 
    *display: inline;
}
.flex-control-thumbs {
    position: static; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-control-thumbs li, 
.flex-control-thumbs li:first-child {
    width: 16%; 
    vertical-align: top; 
    margin: 15px 5% 0 0;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img {
    width: 100%; 
    display: block; 
    opacity: .7; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
    opacity: 1; 
    cursor: default;
}
.product_slider .flex-active-slide a:hover {
    cursor: -webkit-zoom-in; 
    cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
}
```

I have attempted to change several of the above.  Setting height, max-height etc but nothing is working for me.  I didn't write this originally I'm inheriting this.

EDIT: Here is the html:

```
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs"><li><img src="//blah.jpg?v=1546474879" class="flex-active" draggable="false"></li></ol>
```

this part just repeats itself for each image.

Comment: Did you inspect the html on this page to see what was happening? It would be interesting to add the html.

Comment: html part added @AndersonMendes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure, that your images are displayed in one row only. Use the [flexbox model](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#box-model) to achieve this, it's a css standard:

what's new?: in `code .flex-control-thumbs` I changed/added:

`display:flex; flex-wrap:nowrap;`: all image items a placed in the same row

`overflow-x:auto;`: makes sure you have a horizontal scroll bar if needed

```
code .flex-control-thumbs {
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;

  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-x:auto;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

here is working example:

```css
.flex-control-thumbs {
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px; 
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-x:auto;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}

.flex-control-thumbs li {
  margin: 0 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;

}


.flex-control-thumbs li,
.flex-control-thumbs li:first-child {
  width: 16%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 15px 5% 0 0;
  min-width:100px;
}

.flex-control-thumbs img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  opacity: .7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}

.product_slider .flex-active-slide a:hover {
  cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
  cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
}
```

```html
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
  <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="flex-active" draggable="false">
  </li>
    <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="flex-active" draggable="false">
  </li>
    <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="flex-active" draggable="false">
  </li>
    <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="flex-active" draggable="false">
  </li>
    <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="flex-active" draggable="false">
  </li>
    <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="flex-active" draggable="false">
  </li>
    <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="flex-active" draggable="false">
  </li>
    <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="flex-active" draggable="false">
  </li>
    <li>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="flex-active" draggable="false">
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Excelelnt answer, one problem for me on my end.  The overflow appears in mobile device but not on desktop Chrome browser.  Just FYI.  Not really important to me so I"ll mark it as correct any how.  @Vickel

Comment: I've checked in chrome on desktop with this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ahgrpqt/ maybe you have not added the amount of images needed to overflow?

Comment: It works! Does anybody know how to add navigation arrows to flex-control-thumbs list, such as this "Slider with Carousel Slider as Navigation" example? http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

Answer (score 0):

This is all good. But `flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs` doesn't move like this.

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

And I do not have the opportunity to create 2 slides. It is necessary that `flex-control-thumbs` match the currently active image.

And it turns out that yes, `flex-control-thumbs` is really horizontal, but some `flex-control-thumbs` will not be visible if there are a lot of pictures.

And you have to scroll through the slider to find the active
Well, which has `overflow-x: auto; display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap`.

It is not comfortable. It is a pity that the plugin does not have this by default.

Example what I mean
https://www.screencast.com/t/JbOReAW22

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out how to do this. I know this was from 2019 and its 2022 now but it may help others that find there way to this post.

I used the `transform:rotate();` to achieve this.

Here's the code that I got to work

```
.flex-control-nav.flex-control-thumbs{
  flex-direction: column;
  direction: rtl;
  left: 245px;
  top:75%;
  height: 70%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 125px;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transform:rotate(270deg)
}

.flex-control-nav.flex-control-thumbs img {
  height: auto;
  display:block;
  transform:rotate(90deg)
}
```

In those sections you retain the scrolling but now its rotated to "LOOK" horizontal.
Just keep in mind that everything is the opposite now like width, height, top, bottom, left, right, etc...